# R nls gaussian fit "singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates"

Tags: r, gradient, gaussian, nls, singular

I tried to fit my data with a gaussian curve using nls. 
Because that didn't work, i tried to make an  easy example to see what goes wrong:

```
>x=seq(-4,4,0.1)
>y=2*dnorm(x-0.4,2)+runif( length(x) , min = -0.01, max = 0.01)
>df=data.frame(x,y)
>m <- nls(y ~ k*dnorm(x-mu,sigma), data = df, start = list(k=2,mu=0.4,sigma=2))

Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts, upper) :   singular gradient 
matrix at initial parameter estimates
> m <- nls(y ~ k*dnorm(x-mu,sigma), data = df, start == list(k=1.5,mu=0.4,sigma=2))

Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts, upper) :   singular gradient 
matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: First of all, i'm not sure you are using `dnorm` correctly. It's signature is `dnorm(x,mu,sigma)`. Your example is confusing because you have the `mu` variable in the x parameter and `sigma` in the mean parameter. There is no change in variance happening in this example. Is that what you intended? If so, that's a very confusing choice of variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please use `set.seed` to make your example reproducible.  Second I think you meant `dnorm(x, 0.4, 2)` and not `dnorm(x-0.4, 2)`.  These are not the same since in the x-0.4 case the mean of `x-0.4` is `2` and in the other case the standard devaiation is `2`.  If we make this change then it works:

```
set.seed(123)
x=seq(-4,4,0.1)
y=2*dnorm(x, 0.4, 2)+runif( length(x) , min = -0.01, max = 0.01)
df=data.frame(x,y)
nls(y ~ k*dnorm(x, mu,sigma), data = df, start = list(k=2,mu=0.4,sigma=2))
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ k * dnorm(x, mu, sigma)
   data: df
     k     mu  sigma 
2.0034 0.3914 2.0135 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.002434

Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.377e-06
```

Comment: Right, the error was likely from a lack of identify-ability. It's true that `2*dnorm(x-a,2)==2*dnorm(x,2+a)` for all `a` so it's impossible to determine what belongs to the `mu` variable and what belongs to `sigma` in the original formulation.

Comment: sd is the third parameter, not the second.  The problem in the original formula is that both mu and sigma were specifying the mean.

Comment: Yes, I realize that for the `dnorm` function. I was just using the variable names as the OP assigned them. I was just trying to make it clear why NLS wasn't able to solve the formula as originally written.